# Remove all numbers in the text column but error

Tags: r

I have a material A, and I use "select()" to pick out text column,and then using "str_replace_all()" to delete all numbers.

This is the code I wrote. I expect text column will not appear any of numbers, showing only text column without other columns.

```
B<-select(A,text)%>%
text = str_replace_all(text, 
                pattern ="\d",
                replacement="")
B
```

I'm not sure what's wrong in it...
Besides, if i want to reserve other columns,how can I cancel "select()" function and reserve text column which has revised?

Comment: Try `pattern ="\\d"`. Or `pattern ="\\d+"`.